# C++ "Missing vtable" error despite virtual functions defined

Tags: c++, inheritance, vtable

I have two classes called `Sphere` and `Plane` who both inherit from the abstract class `Shape`. The Sphere files were working so I basically copy-pasted them and replaced Sphere with Plane, but now it's throwing this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
   "vtable for rt::Plane", referenced from:
      rt::Plane::Plane() in Scene.cpp.o
    NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [raytracer] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/raytracer.dir/all] Error 2
```

Was that a naive way to do things? I'm very new to C++ so please bear with me. Here are my files:

Shape.h

```
#ifndef SHAPE_H_
#define SHAPE_H_

#include "core/RayHitStructs.h"
#include "core/Material.h"

namespace rt{

class Shape{
public:
    Shape(){};
    virtual ~Shape(){};

    virtual Hit intersect(Ray)=0;

protected:
    Material * material;

};
}
#endif
```

Sphere.h

```
#ifndef SPHERE_H_
#define SPHERE_H_

#include "math/geometry.h"
#include "core/RayHitStructs.h"
#include "core/Shape.h"

namespace rt{

class Sphere:public Shape{

public:
    Sphere(){};
    Sphere(Vec3f center, float radius):center(center), radius(radius){};

    virtual ~Sphere(){};
    Hit intersect(Ray ray);

private:
    Vec3f center;
    float radius;

};
} 
#endif
```

Sphere.cpp

```
#include "Sphere.h"

namespace rt{
    Hit Sphere::intersect(Ray ray){
        Hit h;
        return h;
    }
}
```

Plane.h

```
#ifndef PLANE_H
#define PLANE_H

#include "math/geometry.h"
#include "core/RayHitStructs.h"
#include "core/Shape.h"

namespace rt {
    class Plane:public Shape {

    public:
        Plane(){};
        virtual ~Plane(){};
        Hit intersect(Ray ray);

    };
}

#endif
```

Plane.cpp

```
#include "Plane.h"

namespace rt{
    Hit Plane::intersect(Ray ray){
        Hit h;
        return h;
    }
}
```

Edit: This is the trace when I run `make VERBOSE=1`

```
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.21.3_1/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/raytracer.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++  -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.15 -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names CMakeFiles/raytracer.dir/cameras/Pinhole.cpp.o CMakeFiles/raytracer.dir/cameras/ThinLens.cpp.o CMakeFiles/raytracer.dir/core/Camera.cpp.o CMakeFiles/raytracer.dir/core/LightSource.cpp.o CMakeFiles/raytracer.dir/core/Material.cpp.o CMakeFiles/raytracer.dir/core/RayTracer.cpp.o CMakeFiles/raytracer.dir/core/Scene.cpp.o CMakeFiles/raytracer.dir/core/Shape.cpp.o CMakeFiles/raytracer.dir/lights/AreaLight.cpp.o CMakeFiles/raytracer.dir/lights/PointLight.cpp.o CMakeFiles/raytracer.dir/main/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/raytracer.dir/materials/BlinnPhong.cpp.o CMakeFiles/raytracer.dir/shapes/BVH.cpp.o CMakeFiles/raytracer.dir/shapes/Sphere.cpp.o CMakeFiles/raytracer.dir/shapes/TriMesh.cpp.o CMakeFiles/raytracer.dir/shapes/Triangle.cpp.o -o raytracer
```

Comment: What's the command used to compile & link the code?

Comment: @ChrisMM I'm on MacOS and I just type `make`, I typed `cmake` the first time I built it.

Comment: If the `makefile` was generated by `cmake` try running `make VERBOSE=1` -- that should display the commands as they are run.

Comment: @G.M. Thank you for that, I've run that and updated the post with the trace!

Comment: You don't appear to be linking with `Plane.cpp.o` .

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what that means? I've included `Plane.h` in `Plane.cpp` and I've also included `Plane.h` in the file that's creating `Plane` objects.

Comment: @G.M. Sorry I forgot to @ you in my previous comment.

Comment: I'm worried about a memory leak.

Comment: @sweenish Oh dear that sounds bad, where could it be coming from?

Comment: Re. my previous comment. You need to compile `Plane.cpp` and link with the resulting `Plane.cpp.o` file -- as you have done with other files such as `Shape.cpp`, `Scene.cpp` etc. I suspect this is simply due to an omission in your `CMakeLists.txt` file.

Comment: Not enough code to make it a sure thing, but the `Material*` is potentially leaked.

Comment: @G.M. @sweenish I worked it out! For some reason the compiler wasn't seeing `Plane.cpp` and thought that the `intersect()` wasn't defined, so I had to run `cmake` again and now it works! Thank you for the help (:

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my compiler wasn't seeing `Plane.cpp` and so thought the `intersect()` function was undefined. It worked when I ran `cmake` again. It also worked temporarily when I defined the `intersect()` function in the header file `Plane.h` as well.